# adding two vars together ( php )

Tags: php

I have these two vars, one to display facebook count and one to display twitter count.

so.

To display twitter and facebook count I use.

```
echo "Latest Tweet Count " . $obj->get_tweets() . "<br />"; //to get tweets
echo "Latest Facebook Count " . $obj->get_fb() . "<br />"; //to get facebook total count
```

I want to ADD the count together to show total.

I tried.

```
echo "Total Twitter and FB Count " .$obj->get_tweets()+$obj->get_fb() . "<br />";
```

But isnt working, any idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What about it isn't working? What output do you get?

Comment: Try `var_dump()` and see if `$obj->get_tweets()` and `$obj->get_fb()` actually returns an int.

Comment: example, twitter count is 10, and fb count is 4. Just displays 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really must mix logic with your "view" then you need to be mindful of the order of operations -  ***i.e.*** you want to ensure that the sum of your operands is evaluated **before** either side is concatenated with the rest of the string.  You can achieve this by explicitly wrapping the expression in parenthesis...

```php
echo "Total... ". ( $obj->get_tweets() + $obj->get_fb() ) ."<br />";
//                ^_____________________________________^
```

Answer (score 2):

It's important to know what type of object your dealing with. Adding two strings like `"43"+"86"` won't work. Nor can you add two arrays. But you want a number so you have to get a number value from your object.

If the object is an array

```
count($obj->get_tweets())
```

If it is a string of a number, like "43" instead of 43

```
intval($obj->get_tweets())
```

Comment: just displays the fb count, for some reason. I am not sure how to do var_dump

Comment: Ok so i did this: echo var_dump($obj->get_tweets());
echo var_dump($obj->get_fb()); and it displays int(10)( and int(4)

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning the returned values of get_tweets() and get_fb() to variables.

```
    $tweets = $obj->get_tweets();
    $fbs    = $obj->get_fb();
    $total  = $tweets + $fbs;
    echo "Total Twiter and FB count: $total <br />";
```

This is assuming that both get_tweets() and get_fb() return integers.